# Pull recrods which is not available in another table codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am looking for query result where I can see only Table 1 data which is not in Table 2; Here is my table definition and data;

Table 1

```
id  name    father name age
1      a    a father    60
2      b    b father    70
3      c    c father    60
4      d    d father    50
5      e    e father    20
6      f    f father    32
7      g    g father    40
```

Table 2

```
id  account_amount
1   42
3   90
5   80
7   49
```

Now I want all those records from Table 1 which is either not available in Table 2 or its correspondence account_amount in Table 2 is less than 50. Here would be the required outout

```
id  name    father name age
1      a    a father    60
2      b    b father    70
4      d    d father    50
6      f    f father    32
7      g    g father    40
```

Thanks in advance for solution query in codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With anti join:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.father_name, t1.age
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.account_amount >= 50
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

With not exists:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.father_name, t1.age
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.account_amount >= 50)
```

Since you tagged the question with MySQL the first option gives a little gain in performance.

In the model

```
$this->db->query("SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.father_name, t1.age
       FROM table1 t1
       LEFT JOIN table2 t2
       ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.account_amount >= 50
       WHERE t2.id IS NULL");
```

Imo Active Record is inconvenient for this kind of queries

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
$this->db->select('id');
$excludedData = $this->db->get('table2')->result_array();
foreach($excludedData as $key => $record){
    $excludedData[$key] = $record['id'];
}
$this->db->where_not_in('id',$excludedData);
$desiredData = $this->db->get('table1')->result_array();
```